# How can i make page transitions

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

[Example website](http://www.11-76.com/themes/the-horizon/image-background/)

I want to do this. When i click the links, new div will open transparent and old div will disappear.

What is this jquery name ?

Comment: please make an attempt first, post your code, and then we will help you if it doesn't work...

Comment: It's called "overdesigning" /sarcasm -- It's just a basic `animation` chain, I would imagine.

Comment: $("#DivID1").show(); $("#DivID2").hide()

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could use the on `click` trigger and use `$(#DIV1).fadeOut()` to disappear the old div and `$(#div2).fadeIn()` to show the new div. 
Remember to give the attribute `display: none;` to the second div so this will be hidden until you click trigger "click".  Also, you could use `.slideToggle()`; Check this, there are some examples: [Jquery - .slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)